# Calculated Fields

Tags: delphi

I have dbGrid with a calculated field ... are there any solutions to add different expression to the calculated field ? (each row have its own expression)

Comment: Which Delphi version are you using?

Comment: Show us some code with what you have done so far! Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No, but you can have multiple calculated fields in your table and show/hide them based on a condition.

Comment: In fact you could add a condition to each column based also on the current row number.

Comment: But then he would have to know the row number,eh ? :)

Answer (score 4):

> is there any solutions to add diffrent expresion

It depends what you mean by "add".  You can certainly vary the expression
used to calculate a field's value depending on the values in other fields
in the data row.  For example, given an Order dataset with fields

```
OrderTotal : TFloatField;  //  type = fkCalculated
OrderDiscount : TFloatField;  //  type = fkData
OrderCashPayment : TBooleanField;  //  type = fkData
OrderPricePerUnit : TFloatField;  //  type = fkData
OrderShipping : TFloatField;  //  type = fkData
OrderUnits: TIntegerField;  //  type = fkData
```

then you could have

```
procedure DataModule1.OrderCalcFields(DataSet : TDataSet);
begin
  if OrderCashPayment.AsBoolean then begin
    //  don't charge for shipping
    OrderTotal.AsFloat := OrderPricePerUnit.AsFloat * (1 -  OrderDiscount.AsFloat)
  end
  else begin
    OrderTotal.AsFloat := OrderPricePerUnit.AsFloat * (1 - OrderDiscount.AsFloat) +
      + OrderShipping.AsFloat;
  end;
end;
```

On the other hand if you are asking whether the expression used to calculate
a field's value can be changed at run-time, the answer is also "yes" but you
have to be careful how you do it to avoid impacting performance too much.  You
could use one of the expression-evaluator objects which are available for Delphi
to evaluate an expression supplied as a text-string, preferably one which
parses the expression only when it (the expression) is changed and builds
an expression tree which is repeatedly evaluated in each `OnCalcFields` event.  The freeware Jedi library includes a Pascal interpreter that can be used for run-time expression evaluation and allows the expression to include value derived from e.g. field values, but I can't recollect whether it can do a once-only build of an expression tree.

Answer (score 0):

You must use a function to calculate your expression based on the value of a field.
Example, we want to add a field named *Tax* to the table *employee* of *dbdemos.mdb*, calculated based on *Salary*.

1. Create a new VCL project
2. Add *TADOTable*, *TDataSource* and *TDBGrid* to your form and "wire" them
3. Assign a *ConnectionString* to *ADOTable1*
4. Add a new *Calculated* field of type *Float* to *ADOTable1* and name it *Tax*
5. Go to *Events* of *ADOTable1* and double-click inside *OnCalcFields* and add the following event handler:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.ADOTable1CalcFields(DataSet: TDataSet);
  var
    nSalary, nTax: Double;
begin
  nSalary := ADOTable1Salary.AsFloat;
  if nSalary < 30000 then
    nTax := 10
  else if nSalary < 40000 then
    nTax := 20
  else
    nTax := 30;
  ADOTable1Tax.AsFloat := nSalary * nTax / 100;
end;
```

Comment: Uh?  That's not really how to use a calculated field.  What about when the value of the Tax field is required but not in String format?  You seem to be muddling up changing the text representation of a field value with setting the field's calculated value.

Comment: @MartynA rectified. Thanks.